# How do I rename Git Local and Remote Branch using command?

Tags: git, github, gitlab, bitbucket

I have misspelled the branch name and the reviewer is not approving my Pull request due to the branch name, he suggested renaming my branch name and correct the mistake.

Is there any commands available to update my branch name Locally and Remotely togather?

Comment: There aren't and it is really annoying to do, especially if you have a PR on the branch. It's not like you can see the branch name anywhere after the PR is completed anyway, so ask the reviewer why it matters.

Comment: If you are trying to pull it to another, why does it matter what your local is if it's most likely to be deleted afterwards?